# Need a masonry plugin to replicate this grid or just CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to figure out how this grid layout works: http://www.stories.com/

See how when browser narrows the large images in the third column switch to the small images? Is that done with a masonry plugin? Or it just with CSS by changing the positions of the li elements in media queries?

Comment: Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As remarked, since you didn’t provide any code sample, this probably won’t be helpul to others. Anyway, to answer your question:

They use both JavaScript and CSS, but they don’t change positions with stylesheets. Image sizes do not change, their rather beging reallocated. They’ve got custom methods (like `MasonryFiller` and `calculateLandscapeGrid`) to calculate rows and columns and the positioning of items. They use media queries to change the width and height of standard grid classes (like `.s-1x2`).

In any case, we’ve got lots of native tools like [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/columns) or [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to build it ourselves. Also, calculating absolute positions for child elements is no kind of sorcery. If you still feel like it, you can take a look at field-tested solutions like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) among many others.